# how do I copy/paste in vim ex mode

Tags: vim

I'm increasingly frustrated by typing this

:%s/some_really_long_string/some_other_really_really_long_string_that_may_or_may_not_related_to_the_first_one/gc

Is there any way to copy/paste those strings in ex mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> to insert the value of a register on the Ex command line. If you've yanked some text into the default register, for example, you can recall it with <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>.

There are shortcuts for some common cases, too. You can insert the current word under the cursor with <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>, or the current filename with <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>.

See these topics for more information, including several more examples:

```
:help c_CTRL-R
:help cmdline.txt
```

Registers are worth reading about, too:

```
:help registers
```

Comment: i thought `Ctrl-R` meant you needed to do shift to get the capital `R`. but when i tried it out you just need `ctrl-r` without shift.

Answer (score 10):

I almost always avoid typing the search string in the substitute command by first executing a search (with `/`) or a "word under cursor search" (with `*`) and then executing:

```
:%s//other_string/gc
```

When the search pattern is missing, the substitute command will use the last search pattern.

Beside making you type less characters, the first case, searching with `/`, allow to first test a complex search pattern before executing the substitution.  The second case, searching with `*`, allow to avoid inserting the start/end atoms, i.e. `\<` and `\>`.

--

By the way, you can avoid the `g` flag by adding the line

```
set gdefault
```

in your `vimrc` file.