# VIM: How do you get the last ex command you used?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, text-editors, copy-paste

I find that sometimes I write a really long ex mode command that do lots of stuff. They are sort of "mini-scripts" that I write in the text editor then I start ex mode and copy them into the ex line and execute. But then I always end up editing in the ex mode and then I find it difficult to get the changes i did in ex mode back to my text editing session.

**Using the keyboard, how do you copy the last ex command you used and paste it into your text editor?**

(Note: This is sort of the opposite of this question "[how do I copy/paste in vim ex mode](https://superuser.com/questions/166370/how-do-i-copy-paste-in-vim-ex-mode)" where the user asks "how do you copy from the text editor and paste INTO the ex mode?". My question is the opposite because I wish to copy from the ex mode and paste into my text editor.)

Comment: I have a kludge that does this... but it requires the mouse to select... the gvim pull down menu to copy... and if the ex line is two lines the paste has a new line which is annoying. (but more annoying is the fact that I am using the mouse and the gui to copy/paste...).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `:` register contains the last :-command (ex command) you ran, so you can simply type the command `":p` (with the double quote) to paste that register into the current buffer.  See:

```
:help registers
:help ":
```

Note that there are registers for the last search, the current buffer's name, etc.

Answer (score 21):

Try the `q:` command.  (That's two characters, first `q` and then `:`.)  This is a normal mode command that will open up your ex-command history in a special Vim buffer.  You can review the history, yank anything you want just as always, and/or edit a line and press `<enter>` on it to execute it.

Comment: Just be careful not to type `:q` instead, which my muscle memory tries to force on me!

Comment: `q:` works from normal mode. If you're already in command-line (ex) mode, type Ctrl-F to open that command-line window.

Comment: Hmm.... Ctrl+F does notthing but print "^F" in my ex-mode command line.  Am I missing some magic sauce?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to complement [@Heptite's answer](https://superuser.com/a/230700/1816111). To merely copy the command line into system clipboard (the register `+`), just type `:let @+ = @:`, assuming your vim support `+clipboard` feature, according to [@Saad Malik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39697698/7881370)